# How to listen page scroll in ViewPager to move a something

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager

I use this code to listen to event ViewPager scroll:

```
playingMainViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

                }


            override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

                }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {

                }
        })
```

In onPageScrolled function, positionOffset value move from 0 to 1. 
So how to use value of positionOffset to create an animation an image move from top to bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You should use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer

This will give you scrolled offset for performing animations.